# Too much space after opting out of hats

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Once I click "No hats for me, please", this shows up:

[image]

Suggesting me to "love hats" (which I do).

But there is a very big white space above the text, which looks very strange to me.

Wouldn't it be nice to make the dialog smaller, with the text higher or fill some decorations inside the gap?

Comment: Maybe it wants to convince you to love hats by showing how empty your life would be without them?

Comment: @RafaelTavares Haha maybe!

Comment: I assume it's just fitting in with the recent theme: "We heard you like whitespace, so we gave you lots of whitespace."

Comment: Defender of unicorn ?

Comment: It probably is the same space as where you would normally see your recent awarded hats, but you have none since you don't like hats.

Comment: The whole icon should be removed from the menu.

Comment: @curiousdannii Agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users who truly don't want any space on the site taken up by hats or Winter Bash can use a user style in their favorite browser add-on for such things (e.g. Stylus) to hide all things Winter Bash (including the hats on others' profile pictures) with the following styles:

```css
a.icon-winterbash, .user-info .hat {
    display: none !important;
}

a#wb-hat-count {
    display: none !important;
}

a div.hat {
    display: none !important;
}
```

That results in no space being taken up at all:

[image: Screenshot of the top bar with no Winter Bash icon visible, highlighted by a red underline for emphasis]